# SQL SERVER Pivot rows to column

Tags: sql-server

I have the input as

```
123   1    Y    Active

123   1    Y    Idle

109   1    Y    Active

109   1    Y    Away

165   1    Y    Active

145   1    Y    Idle
```

I need the output as :

```
123  1  Y   Active and Idle

109  1  Y   Active and Away

165  1  Y   Active Only

145  1  Y   Idle Only

SELECT distinct COl1,Col2,Col3 ,
case when Col4 = 'Active' and Col4 = 'Idle' then 'Active and Idle'
when Col4 = 'Active' and Col4 = 'Away' then 'Active and Away'
when Col4 = 'Active' then  'Active Only'
when Col4 = 'Idle' then  'Idle Only'

end  as category
from Person
```

I tried the above query but it is not working  and it wont work because i am 
trying to convert multiple rows to 1 column, which is not possible with 
Case.

I have to try something like PIVOT, but not able to implement . Any help?

Comment: which version you are using.? [String_Agg in 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples)

Comment: What is someone had values for `'Idle'`, `'Active'` and `'Away'`, what would be the value then? Really stuff like this should be done in your presentation layer; SQL Server isn't the best place for turning data into language based text.

Comment: Your code doesn't PIVOT anything. The number of columns remains the same. The code is *aggregating strings*

Answer (score 2):

You need `FOR XML PATH()` approach :

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.col1, STUFF(pp.Col4, 1, 4, '') AS category
FRPM Person p CROSS APPLY
     ( SELECT ' AND ' + p1.Col4 
       FROM Person p1
       WHERE P1.col1 = p.col1 
       FOR XML PATH('')
     ) pp(Col4);
```

By this way `FOR XML PATH('')` would return xml element for each `col1` & outer query `STUFF()` will replace `AND` with `''` at the start of position of string.

Comment: You mean, the OP needs to aggregate strings. That's still not enough to produce the desired output. Not my downvote btw.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. . .  Yes but someone has downvoted without any comment.

Comment: You didn't explain how XML was used

Comment: Appending `+ IIF(count(*)>1,'',' Only')     
from @table` to the expression should be enough to produce the desired result

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
declare @table table(
col1 int,col2 int,col3 nvarchar(10),col4 nvarchar(50)
)

insert into @table values(123,   1,    'Y'    ,'Active')
insert into @table values(123,   1,    'Y'    ,'Idle')
insert into @table values(109,   1,    'Y'    ,'Active')
insert into @table values(109,   1,    'Y'    ,'Away')
insert into @table values(165,   1,    'Y'    ,'Active')
insert into @table values(145,   1,    'Y'    ,'Idle')


select col1,col2,col3, stuff((SELECT ' AND ' + t2.col4 + CASE WHEN count(t1.col1) = 1 THEN ' ONLY' ELSE '' END
                        FROM @table t2
                        WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1
                        ORDER BY t2.col1
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
            ,1,5,'') AS col4
from @table t1
group by col1,col2,col3
```

I'm using the `stuff` to concat values that does not include in the group.

And when `count =  1` its mean that there is only one item in this group so you need to add the `Only` suffix.

Comment: Once again, no explanation and doesn't produce the desired output

Comment: `Idle Only`. Single values have suffixes. This answer doesn't explain that *aggregation* should be used instead of pivoting

Comment: it does have the suffix try run it!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I dont understand what do you want, It works perfect, As Abcdf asked...

Comment: @StackOverflow no explanation and the relevant code *is hidden*. Code only questions aren't good questions.

Comment: @bat7 explain what your code does and make sure it's visible. Code-only answers don't help either the OP or anyone else faced with the same problem

Answer (score 1):

That's not such an obvious question, even in SQL Server 2017 which provides `STRING_AGG`. A check is needed to append `Only` if there is only one row per group.

Given this table :

```
declare @table table (id int, flag1 int, flag2 char(1), status varchar(40))

insert into @table 
values
(123,1,'Y','Active'),
(123,1,'Y','Idle'),
(109,1,'Y','Active'),
(109,1,'Y','Away'),
(165,1,'Y','Active'),
(145,1,'Y','Idle')
```

The following query will return the aggregated values. If there's only one value, it will append `Only` :

```
select id,flag1,flag2,
    string_agg(status,' and ') + IIF(count(*)>1,'',' Only')     
from @table
group by id,flag1,flag2
```

This produces  :

```
109 1   Y   Active and Away
123 1   Y   Active and Idle
145 1   Y   Idle Only
165 1   Y   Active Only
```